# Activiti - Parent process of subprocess

Tags: subprocess, workflow, activiti

We are using the Activiti workflow engine on this scenario:

[image: Flow]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
<signal id="alertSignal" name="alert" />
  <process id="myProcess" name="myProcess" isExecutable="true">
    <subProcess id="subprocess1" name="Sub Process">
      <startEvent id="startevent2" name="Start"></startEvent>
      <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
      <userTask id="verifico-id-transitorio-paciente" name="verifico-id-transitorio-paciente">
        <extensionElements>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoTarea(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoDependencia(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
        </extensionElements>
      </userTask>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent2" targetRef="verifico-id-transitorio-paciente"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="verifico-id-transitorio-paciente" targetRef="parallelgateway1"></sequenceFlow>
      <parallelGateway id="parallelgateway1" name="Parallel Gateway"></parallelGateway>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow10" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="ingreso-formulario-ConMed"></sequenceFlow>
      <intermediateThrowEvent id="signalintermediatethrowevent1" name="SignalThrowEvent">
        <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
      </intermediateThrowEvent>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow11" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="signalintermediatethrowevent1"></sequenceFlow>
      <userTask id="ingreso-formulario-ConMed" name="ingreso-formulario-ConMed">
        <extensionElements>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoTarea(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoDependencia(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
        </extensionElements>
      </userTask>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow13" sourceRef="ingreso-formulario-ConMed" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    </subProcess>
    <subProcess id="subprocess2" name="Sub Process">
      <startEvent id="startevent3" name="Start"></startEvent>
      <endEvent id="endevent2" name="End"></endEvent>
      <userTask id="ingreso-formulario-Con" name="ingreso-formulario-Con">
        <extensionElements>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoTarea(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
          <activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{INTERNA_LOGICA_TRAMITE.setearPermisoDependencia(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
        </extensionElements>
      </userTask>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="startevent3" targetRef="ingreso-formulario-Con"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow6" sourceRef="ingreso-formulario-Con" targetRef="endevent2"></sequenceFlow>
    </subProcess>
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <subProcess id="subprocess3" name="Sub Process">
      <userTask id="modifico-formulario-ConMed" name="modifico-formulario-ConMed">
        <extensionElements>
        </extensionElements>
      </userTask>
      <startEvent id="startevent4" name="Start"></startEvent>
      <endEvent id="endevent3" name="End"></endEvent>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow8" sourceRef="startevent4" targetRef="modifico-formulario-ConMed"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow9" sourceRef="modifico-formulario-ConMed" targetRef="endevent3"></sequenceFlow>
    </subProcess>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="subprocess1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="subprocess1" targetRef="subprocess2"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent4" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="subprocess2" targetRef="endevent4"></sequenceFlow>
    <startEvent id="signalstartevent1" name="Signal start">
      <signalEventDefinition signalRef="alertSignal"></signalEventDefinition>
    </startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow14" sourceRef="signalstartevent1" targetRef="subprocess3"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

And the act_ru_execution table shows like the 2 subprocess's are 2 independent process's with no parent:

[image]

Is it possible to get the parent process of a subprocess and how it gets represented on activiti's database ? Because we are not finding that relation.

Is it possible to pass all variables of the main process to a subprocess in our scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parent process**

*How to get in ServiceTask:*

Select the process instance that have as sub process instance the given process instance. Note that there will always be maximum only **one** such process instance that can be the result of this query.
    runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().subProcessInstanceId(subProcessInstanceId).list();

*In database:*

ACT_RU_EXECUTION there are two attributes PARENT_ID_ and SUPER_EXEC_.

- PARENT_ID_ id of execution which is up in the tree hierarchy but in one process (e.g. parallel execution, ...)
- SUPER_EXEC_ id of the super execution in process/subprocess relation

**Example of ACT_RU_EXECUTION table of process with parallel executions and one sub-process:**
[image]

**Pass all variables to a subprocess**

Manually in process definition or dynamically by listener implementation.

Comment: the super_exec_id_ is null, i edited the question with that information. What could we be doing wrong ?

Comment: With a signal boundary event i got the espected behaviour with parent_id. Is it possible to achieve this behavior with process's instead of executions ?. In other words, subprocess's beeing actual process's and not executions. And those process's have a common parent process, is that even possible ?

Comment: I added image of relations in ACT_RU_EXECUTION table in one process. But in your case, you are right. The process initiated by signal is independent. If you want get connection with instance that is throwing signal, you have to use signal boundary event.

Comment: Activiti user guide: By default, signals are broadcast process engine wide. This means that you can throw a signal event in a process instance, and other process instances with different process definitions can react on the occurrence of this event. However, sometimes it is wanted to react to a signal event only within the same process instance. A use case for example is a synchronization mechanism in the process instance, if two or more activities are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

During the execution the key to determine a sub-process is given as `<parent_process_id>-<sub-process-id>`. this **key** will give you desired result if you query for the key of subprocess by - `runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processDefinitionKey("your-key")`